# Expo Document Picker iOS Release

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

last week we created an app with expo, where the user can use the [DocumentPicker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker.html) function. It’s work as expected when running in the expo app (debug and published too) in both iOS and Android, but when we finally made a build for android beta testing and ios testflight, we found that in iOS it does not work.
If I check the expo generated provisioning in apple developer, i don’t see enabled icloud service. Maybe thats the problem?

Any advice?

(Tried with both Expo version 20.0.0 and 21.0.0)

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Did you add `"usesIcloudStorage": true,` in your `app.json` under `"ios"` key ? And did you go around the issue ? I'm experiencing exactly the same.

Comment: FYI there's an open issue on Github: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/589